# How exactly is spinor with Grassmann variables as component defined?

Tags: supersymmetry, spinors, grassmann-numbers

I'm reading K. Muller's *Introduction to Supersymmetry* about spinor representation. He said that the components of a spinor are Grassmann variables.

I understood Grassmann variables as follows. For a vector space $V=\rm{span}\{\theta_1,\cdots,\theta_n\}$, the direct sum
$$
\Lambda(V)=\mathbb{C}\oplus V\oplus(V\wedge V)\oplus\cdots\oplus\wedge^nV
$$
forms an algebra under wedge product $\wedge$.

On the other hand, Muller constructed Weyl spinors as elements of two representation spaces $\psi\in F$ and $\bar{\psi}\in\dot{F}$. Their components $\psi_1,\psi_2,\bar{\psi}_{\dot{1}},\bar{\psi}_{\dot{2}}$ are Grassmann variables. It seems that he meant these $\psi_i\in V$ instead of $\psi_i\in\Lambda(V)$.

My question is that what's the dimension of $V$ here $n=?$ At first I thought $n=4$ and $V=\rm{span}\{\psi_1,\psi_2,\bar{\psi}_{\dot{1}},\bar{\psi}_{\dot{2}}\}$, but
$$
(\sigma^0)_{A\dot{B}}\epsilon^{\dot{B}\dot{C}}\bar{\psi}_{\dot{C}}=\psi_A
$$
seems to suggest that $\psi_A$ and $\bar{\psi}_{\dot{A}}$ are linear dependent. But if $n=2$, the expressions like $(\theta\psi)(\theta\phi)$ will simply be $0$?

Comment: K. Muller?? Do you mean Harald J. W. Müller-Kirsten? Link to abstract page? On which page is $V$ defined?

Answer (score 2):

1. DeWitt [1] defines the set of [supernumbers](https://planetmath.org/supernumber) as the [exterior algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exterior_algebra)
   $$\begin{array}{rccccl} \bigwedge{}^{\bullet} V  &~=~&  \bigwedge{}^{\rm even} V &\oplus&  \bigwedge{}^{\rm odd} V& \cr
   && ||| &&|||& \cr
   && \mathbb{C}^{1|0} && \mathbb{C}^{0|1} &\cr
   && ||| &&|||& \cr
   && \mathbb{C}_c && \mathbb{C}_a \cr
   && ||| &&||| &\cr
   &&\{c\text{-numbers}\}  && \{a\text{-numbers}\}& 
   \end{array}$$
   of an infinite-dimensional vector space $V$. So $n=\infty$, cf. OP's question.
2. When considering an equation that is linear in $\psi$ (such as, e.g. the transformation rule for a spinor representation), it becomes agnostic to whether we treat $\psi$ as Grassmann-odd or Grassmann-even.

   E.g. Ref. 2 flips on p. 49 the Grassmann-parity of the left- and right-handed Weyl spinor representations $F$ and $\dot{F}$ from Grassmann-even to Grassmann-odd.
3. For more information, see also e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/494379/2451) & [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/40746/2451) related Phys.SE posts.

References:

1. Bryce DeWitt, *Supermanifolds,* Cambridge Univ. Press, 1992.
2. H.J.W. Müller-Kirsten & A. Wiedemann, *Intro to SUSY,* 2010.